# Vaadin production build is not running properly

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin23

My Vaadin (ver 23.1.2)-spring boot app builds and runs perfectly in development mode, but with the production build, it just hangs loading. Any Idea how to find the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the browser console, what is hanging? Or the server-side logging?

Comment: Not a specific error on server-side logging. it is just the top line progress bar (the default loading progress bar that a vaadin app provides) blinking for ever. the only thing that might be an issue is an info (not a warning) line on the build logs that says: "Unable to determine version information. No vaadin_versions.json found"

Comment: Here is the error log that I get looking at the browser console:

generated-flow-imports.ad5b832f.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _e.register is not a function
at generated-flow-imports.ad5b832f.js:19:8
(anonymous) @ generated-flow-imports.ad5b832f.js:19
Promise.catch (async)
render @ indexhtml.d3eb68c9.js:1
__onNavigationEvent @ indexhtml.d3eb68c9.js:1
setRoutes @ indexhtml.d3eb68c9.js:1
(anonymous) @ indexhtml.d3eb68c9.js:203

Comment: I fixed this issue by removing the autocomplete component that I had used. That component caused this issue.